# Seeking Photo Management Software for genealogical research?

Tags: software-recommendations, photo

I am searching for a photo management software to help organize and tag all the photos gathered for my genealogical research. I know that there is a lot of software that allows me to edit the Meta-data and to use keywords, but I also would like to be able to save comments on some part of a photo. For example, I want to be able to give names to persons on big family photos without just writing something like "2nd row, 8th person".

Does anyone know a photo management software that allows me to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[PhotoIdent](http://www.photoident.de/index.php/en/), a product from Germany, has the requested features. As it features a English website, I assume there is an English language version of the software too. I haven't tried it personally.

Answer (score 5):

Calico Pie's *Family Historian* software allows the user to add photos and link faces in the photos to their entries in FH.  The [feature list](https://www.family-historian.co.uk/features/feature-list) says:

> In Family Historian, not only can you add as many pictures as you like for each person, you can add a picture once and link it to each
>   person in the picture. The best family photographs are usually the
>   ones which have more than one family member in them. In Family
>   Historian, you can link each person to their own face in each picture
>   they’re in – without having to ‘crop’ your pictures. By using Family
>   Historian in this way you add value to your pictures by recording who
>   each person is, while at the same time adding value to your family
>   tree research by making it much more visual. You can display pictures
>   (and faces from pictures) in diagrams and reports, and family tree CDs
>   & DVDs, and websites. Family Historian will by default use up to 9
>   pictures of each individual in the main program window.
>
> You can also add sounds, video and any other kind of multimedia. You
>   can even add links to other family tree files.

Screenshots of the feature are on FH's [tour](https://www.family-historian.co.uk/tour) page, in the Pictures and Multimedia section, and as part of the [Quick Start Guide](https://www.family-historian.co.uk/quick-start-guide).

Calico Pie's You Tube channel has a tutorial that was posted using an older version: [Adding Pictures and Linking Faces (in Family Historian 5)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fQK52hccSI0).

A [30-day free trial](https://www.family-historian.co.uk/downloads/free-30-day-trial) is available. The trial is fully functional except for a few features like plugins.

Disclaimer: I am not associated with Calico Pie. I am a long-time user of Family Historian and a member of the [FH Users Group](https://www.fhug.org.uk/) -- for more information, see FHUG's Forum and Knowledge Base.

Comment: Sounds like the feature I am searching for, but unfortunately I am using Gramps for some time now, and I dont really want to switch. I'm more searching for an additional program, that I can also use when visiting relatives, and that allows me to make quick comments on the pictures, without worrying too much about the correct citations in my genealogy software.

Comment: Marvin it is worth checking out Family Historian, you can easily import your Gramps data into it. I have given you an answer above but Jan's suggestion is what I use.

Comment: @MarvinDippell -- at Stack Exchange we need to make the Q/As of broad interest.  I understand why you might not want to transfer your Gramps data into Family Historian, but in case other people see this question and haven't chosen their main genealogy software yet, we need an answer that says FH can do it

Answer (score 4):

You can do what you want in any of the major photo editing programmes such as Photoshop, Photoshop Elements, Gimp etc. The thing to do is to increase the canvas size so that you have a large white area below the photo. Print it out and write the names in the appropriate people in it when you visit a relative and then when you get home use the same programme to add the names in properly.

This is an example [image: Example]

Answer (score 3):

As you say you are using Gramps, you can install the [photo tagging gramplet](https://gramps-project.org/wiki/index.php/Photo_Tagging_Gramplet). You can just use this manually or if you have OpenCV installed it will automatically find faces.

I’ve used it and found it to be quite good.